# After Post Method There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'DepartmentId'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The Drop Down List is generated perfectly on HttpGet Method for Create Action. 
But when it comes to HttpPost Action Create it compiles this error:

> There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that
>   has the key 'DepartmentId'.

I Know that this question has been asked multiple of times.
I have truly tried most of the methods like:

1. changing the name of the list .
2. Put the Select List in a View Data instead of ViewBag
3. Cast The ViewBag.Departments in my view to IEnumerable or SelectList

None of these trials fixed my problem. Here is my Code:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Create")]
public ActionResult Create_Get()
{
    using (MyConnectionString _context = new MyConnectionString())
    {
        var list = (from d in _context.Departments
                    select new
                    {
                        d.DepartmentId,
                        d.DepartmentName
                    }).ToList();
        SelectList dList = new SelectList(list, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName");
        ViewBag.DepartmentId = dList;
    }

    Employee employee = new Employee();
    return View(employee);
}

[HttpPost]
[ActionName("Create")]
public ActionResult Create_Post()
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee();
        TryUpdateModel(employee);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (MyConnectionString _context = new MyConnectionString())
            {
                _context.Employees.Add(employee);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
    return View();
}
```

View:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("DepartmentId", ViewBag.DepartmentId as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: *"when it comes to HttpPost Action"* - The code you're showing doesn't have an HTTP POST action.  Note the `[HttpGet]` method attribute.  Can you clarify the problem?

Comment: you want me to display the HttpPost Action also .? @David

Comment: Well, if the problem happens in your `[HttpPost]` action, then you *probably* want to take a look at your `[HttpPost]` action.

Comment: @David Done , you can see it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as the error states, the `ViewBag` has no such data.  Note how you set this value in your `[HttpGet]` action:

```
ViewBag.DepartmentId = dList;
```

So when you return the view, that value is available to the view.  Your `[HttpPost]` action returns the same view.  But it returns it without any model and, specifically to regarding this error, without ever setting anything in the `ViewBag`.

Before you return the view, set the `ViewBag` values you need in your controller action.  Exactly as you already do in your `[HttpGet]` action.

(Since the functionality would be repeated, you are of course encouraged to extract it into a common method rather than just copying/pasting all of the same code.  You're also encouraged to use a model instead of relying on `ViewBag`, but that may just come down to a matter of personal preference.)

---

**Edit:** *As requested in a comment below, an example:*

For example, notice how you set your `ViewBag` value in your `[HttpGet]` action:

```
using (MyConnectionString _context = new MyConnectionString())
{
    var list = (from d in _context.Departments
                select new
                {
                    d.DepartmentId,
                    d.DepartmentName
                }).ToList();
    SelectList dList = new SelectList(list, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName");
    ViewBag.DepartmentId = dList;
}
```

If you want to set the exact same value in your `[HttpPost]` action, then simply do the *exact same thing*:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // ... the code you have in here is unchanged
}

using (MyConnectionString _context = new MyConnectionString())
{
    var list = (from d in _context.Departments
                select new
                {
                    d.DepartmentId,
                    d.DepartmentName
                }).ToList();
    SelectList dList = new SelectList(list, "DepartmentId", "DepartmentName");
    ViewBag.DepartmentId = dList;
}
return View();
```

Comment: would you please add an example after your explanation . i did not understand what you mean 100% . And Thank you @David

Comment: @markdibe: Answer updated.  But you already have an example... Your `[HttpGet]` action.  If you want to set the exact same value in your `[HttpPost]` action, then you would set that value the exact same way.  All you have to do is the same thing you've already done.

Comment: But how will i know what value (id) is selected if i just regenerate the ViewBag ? @David

Comment: @markdibe: That sounds like an entirely different question.  Where do you capture or store the selected value at all?  Your `[HttpPost]` action doesn't receive any data.  Are you somehow pulling that data from the `Request` object directly in `TryUpdateModel()`?  If so then that's where you would have that information.  Though you're encouraged to use model binding instead of directly accessing the `Request` object for form values.  But the code shown doesn't include any form post, or any selected value, or anything of that nature.  This addresses only the error you're asking about.

Comment: can i have a 5 minutes from your time ? chatting please

Comment: Department list is from database , I do have a deprartmentId in the model Employee . DepartmentId should be filled from the drop downlist already filled

Comment: @markdibe: Ideally your `[HttpPost]` action should be receiving a model as a method argument, *probably* an instance of `Employee`.  The form element names should match the property names on the model.  That would be where the selected value is known.  This, however, is unrelated to the question being asked above.  Please understand that a Stack Overflow comment thread is not a replacement for tutorials and practice.  You are encouraged to consult some introductory tutorials on ASP.NET MVC and start with some simple examples of posting a form.

Comment: @markdibe: If you have moved past the error in the question and have encountered a new problem, you are encouraged to post a new Stack Overflow question with the details of that problem.

Comment: But your answer did not solve the problem . It keeps giving the same issue

Comment: @markdibe: Did you try the suggested approach in this answer?  Is the error from the question still present?  Show your updated code in the question and, if the error has changed *in any way*, include the updated error.

Comment: Yes it still with the same error . I have just copied the one you made

Comment: @markdibe: Please don't attempt to edit information into answers, instead you should edit information into the question.  Please also don't use screenshots of code, as they can not be searched/copied/etc. and are difficult to read.  As for the information you were trying to convey... In the screenshot you are setting the `ViewBag` value when returning the *redirect*.  You need to set it when returning the *view*, since the error is happening on that view.

Comment: thank you so much david  for your help .the problem was that i should call the viewbag again before checking if the model is valid or not

Comment: i am sorry i thought i was adding it to my question . Sorry again